# Get The Latest Email From EWS

Tags: vb.net, email, datetime, exchangewebservices, searchfiltercollection

Can anyone help me, I need to **retrieve only the very latest email** in my **exchange server inbox**.

I **don't need any other email** to show up with the one I want.

But I'm stuck, since the **farthest** that I could get is only the **email I received only today.**

I use SearchFilter with DateTimeReceived :

Here's the **snipped of my code** for the **filter** :

```
Dim search As New SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, DateTime.Today.Date)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort your search results by the `DateTimeReceived` property, in descending order.

```
view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
```

Then when you loop through the results, the first email will be the latest (and then you can jump out of the loop).

Comment: Thanks for the help but, it seems maybe I wasn't clear enough. I only want and need to display the very latest email. I don't need the others

Comment: This will get you the latest email. You can just jump out of the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: thanks a lot for you suggestion. It does work. Sorry I just replied and verified your answer today, because yesterday I was still busy figuring out how to make it loop once.

Comment: hey, do you happen to know how to split an email that has a reply? Because mine if it has a reply it will show the original email along with the reply. Which I only need the latest reply (only the reply text)?

Comment: No problem, your welcome. I would advise you to write a new question for your 'split email' issue. Please include your code in the new question

Comment: hey, I've posted a new Q for the split email issue under this url : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845683/split-email-body-vb-net" so if you can help me it will be appriciated. Thanks